# handlebars not receiving object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Handlebars is refusing to cooperate. I have this template

```
<script id="edit_client_modal" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <fieldset>

        <input type="text" class="" value="{{name}}" />
        <input type="text" class="" value="{{email}}" />
        <input type="text" class="" value="{{phone}}" />                        

    </fieldset>
```

And I try to populate it with some values like this

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
var current_data = {
        "name": $.trim(tr.find("td.contact_name").text()),
        "email": $.trim(tr.find("td.contact_email").text()),
        "phone": $.trim(tr.find("td.contact_phone").text())
    }


var source = $("#edit_client_modal").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
var options = {options: current_data};

edit_contact_html = template(options);
```

But the `input`s don't get populated with the values. What's wrong here?

Comment: your data is a child of `options` and your template does not handle that. You can add `{{with options}}` to the template or give handlebars the raw data `template(current_data)`

Comment: I should literally add the string `{{with options}}` to the top of the template? That didn't work for me

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/#builtins

Comment: @Malk is there an advantage to one over the other?

Comment: @Malk How exactly would the second answer look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is looking for 3 properties: `{name:'',email:'',phone:''}`

But the object you are passing has only the single `options` property. So it cannot find these values and leaves them blank.

You can:

- Adjust the template to use the `options` block:

  `<fieldset>
  {{#with options}}
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{name}}" />
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{email}}" />
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{phone}}" />
  {{/with}}
  </fieldset>`
- Adjust the template to use the correct path

  `<fieldset>
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{options.name}}" />
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{options.email}}" />
      <input type="text" class="" value="{{options.phone}}" />
  </fieldset>`
- Leave the template alone and adjust the javascript to not wrap these values in an options field:

  `edit_contact_html = template(current_data);`